# Configuring highlight color of UIButton with background image for normal state

Tags: ios5, uibutton

If a UIButton's background image is set for normal state, UIControlStateNormal, is it feasible to configure the selection color without another image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the same background image for UIControlStateHighlighted and set button text color for the same highlighted state.

Hope this is what you required.